# Bootstrap datetime picker option to select from every half hour

Tags: bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Is there a way to make bootstrap datetime picker to show me only options that represent intervals of half hour? (8:00; 8:30; 9:00; 9:30; ...)

Also I would like to know if there are ways to limit time intervals (say start from 8:00 AM until 18:00 PM).

Answer (score 9):

You can set interval with the `stepping` parameter, while you can use `enabledHours` to limit valid hours of day. Assuming that "datetimepicker" is the id of your component, you can initialize it as follows:

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    stepping: 30,
    enabledHours: [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
});
```

You can find further information in the [official documentation of the library](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/)

Answer (score 3):

For me it works:-

`$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    autoclose:true,
    minuteStep: 30,
    hoursDisabled: [19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 00, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
});`

Comment: This should have been a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, 
[you will be able to post comments](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).